# What is significance of Thaipusam Festival?

Tags: worship, festivals, kartikeya

Thaipusam is an important festival celebrated by Tamil speaking Hindus all over the world. What is its significance and legends? What is Kevatti Ceremony?

Comment: There are various reasons believed to be responsible for this festival but am putting this as a comment since I do not have scriptural references for the same. The festival commemorates the occasion when Parvati gave Kartikeya a spear so he could vanquish the demon Surapadman who was the elder brother of Tarakasur. Kavadis bear the offerings that devotees offer to the Lord for the sake of tiding over a great calamity similar to the Kavadiyes you find in north India dedicated to Lord Shiva.